# Filter Drop Down values for entered Input Field Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array which contains numbers from 0 to 100.

If I click div element there will be one dropdown shown where all these array elements will be shown.
but if i type a number in text field e.g 0, drop down should show values of array contains[0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100] automatically.
e.g if we type a number 10, drop down should show values of the array contains [10,100];

Can someone suggest me a logic?

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filtering array values based on input value and then change content of dropdown based on filtered array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function.

```
//let arr = Array.apply(null, {length: 101}).map(Number.call, Number);

//arr is your array

//num is the number you want to search for

function filterArr(num) {
  return arr
    .map(i => i.toString())
    .filter(i => i.includes(num.toString()))
    .map(i => parseInt(i));
}

console.log(filterArr(0));//logs [ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 ]
```

Hope this helps. As you have not provided any code, you might not be able to use this solution as-is. But the logic should work for you.